# Implementing inverse FFT using forward FFT and time-reversal property

Tags: fft, python, ifft

I am trying to implement an inverse FFT using the forward FFT. For clarity:

Let S[t] be a signal in time, and S[w] the transformed signal. As per [this site](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4210789/DSP-Tricks--Computing-inverse-FFTs-using-the-forward-FFT), it seems one can reverse S[w], use the forward FFT routine, then reverse the resulting signal again and this should give S[t]. I won't go into why should it work but it's all in the link provided.

I attempted to try this method, and it seems to recreate the signal when I use a high sample rate. However, it seems that even if I do not go over the Nyquist frequency, I encounter some weird effect. Here is my code in NumPy:

```
# Generate a signal of s cosine with 200 [Hz]
f = 200
Fs = 10
t = np.linspace(-10,10,Fs*20)
s = cos(2*np.pi*f*t)

# Take fft
u = np.fft.fft(s)

# Reverse in time
u = u[::-1]

# Transform again
u_t = np.fft.fft(u)

# Reverse and normalize
s_new = np.divide(u_t[::-1],s.shape[-1])

# Finally slice for easier viewing
plt.plot(t[1:100],s_new[1:100])
plt.plot(t[1:100],s[1:100])
```

This code yields the following graph:
[image]

I am a little confused, the theory looked sound and I can't think what I did wrong here.

**Note**: I tried calling `np.fft.fft` and then `np.fft.ifft` and the reconstruction goes as planned. Therefore I believe this problem is not due to aliasing.

**Edit:** I made way by simply taking the complex conjugation instead of reversing (using `np.conj()` where I reverse). This solves the problem, but I still do not understand why reversing in time does not accomplish a conjugation, so I'd love someone to explain it to me. I leave the modified code in case it helps someone else:

```
# Generate a signal
f = 200
Fs = 10
t = np.linspace(-10,10,Fs*20)
s = cos(2*np.pi*f*t)

# Take fft
u = np.fft.fft(s)

# Conjugate
u = np.conj(u)

# Transform again
u_t = np.fft.fft(u)

# conjugate and normalize
s_new = np.divide(np.conj(u_t),s.shape[-1])

# Finally slice for easier viewing
plt.plot(t[1:100],s_new[1:100])
plt.plot(t[1:100],s[1:100])
```

Comment: 1) `f=200;Fs=10` 2) What is the purpose of the time reversal in your code? Try to spot the differences in the forward and inverse transforms [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html). Something is indeed **flipped** between the forward and inverse transforms but that is certainly not the time order of the samples (?).

Comment: @A_A I think the link I provided explains the rational (-:

Answer (score 5):

In your link I cannot find a reference to the time-reversal. However, here are some additions:

The time reversal $y(t)$ of a continuous signal $x(t)$ is given by $y(t)=x(-t)$. Similarly, for a discrete signal we have $y[n]=x[-n]$. However, here the delicate issue occurs that $n=0...N-1$, where $N$ is the signal length. Now, noting that in the finite discrete domain every signal is considered to be periodic with $N$, you get 
$$y[n] = x[-n] = x[(-n)_N]$$

where $(x)_N$ is the modulo operation of $x$ by $N$. Hence, time-reversal in the discrete domain is not just reading your vector from back to front. Instead, the first element remains the same ($n=0$) and the others are read from back to front.

Now coming to the time-reversal property wtih the Fourier Transform:

- $FFFF=I$ where $F$ is the (unitary) Fourier transform operator and $I$ is the identity. I.e. applying 4 times the (forward) Fourier transform yields the original signal.
- Hence, logically $FFF=F^H$, where $F^H$ is the inverse Fourier Transform (yes, it is also the Hermitian of the forward transform). However, calculating inverse FFT by 3 times forward FFT is not very efficient...
- Further, we know $FF=T$ where $T$ is the inflection operator $(Tx)[n]=x[-n]$, again read with the modulo interpretation.

Hence, we find $F^H=TF$, i.e. in order to caculate inverse FFT, you can do forward FFT and time-reverse the result:

```
f = 0.1
Fs = 10
t = np.linspace(-10,10,Fs*20)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t*(t+1))

# Take fft
U = np.fft.fft(s)

# Transform again
u_t = np.fft.fft(U)

# Reverse and normalize

s_new = np.divide(u_t[-np.arange(u_t.shape[0])],s.shape[-1])

# Finally slice for easier viewing
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot(t,s_new)
plt.plot(t,s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Short if $X[k]$ represents the $N$-point $FFT$ of an $N$-point signal $x[n]$ , then $N * x[n]$ (sequence $x[n]$ scaled by $N$) can be obtained by performing $FFT$ on the sequence $X[0], X[N-1], X[N-2], \cdots ,X[1]$.

**Explanation:**

Consider the equation of $IFFT$

$$IFFT: x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( \sum_{k=0}^{N−1}X[k].e^{j2πnk/N} )$$

It can be split and written in the following way

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( X[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}X[k].e^{j2πnk/N} )$$

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( X[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}X[N - k].e^{j2πn(N-k)/N} )$$

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( X[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}X[N - k].e^{j2πn(N)/N}.e^{-j2πn(k)/N})$$

The term $e^{j2πn(N)/N}$ evaluates to one and hence the above can be re written as

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( X[0] + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}X[N - k].e^{-j2πn(k)/N})$$

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( X[0].e^{-j2π(0)(k)/N} + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}X[N - k].e^{-j2πn(k)/N})$$

Consider a series $Y[k]$ defined as follows

$$Y[0] = X[0]$$ and

$$Y[k] = X[N-k]$$ $for$  $k = 1,2,\cdots,N-1$

Then the last of the above equation can be re written as

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( Y[0].e^{-j2π(0)(k)/N} + \sum_{k=1}^{N−1}Y[k].e^{-j2πn(k)/N})$$

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( \sum_{k=0}^{N−1}Y[k].e^{-j2πn(k)/N})$$

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} ( FFT(Y[k]))$$

Where $Y[k]$ is the series obtained from rearrangement of  $X[k]$

$X[0], X[N-1], X[N-2], \cdots, X[1]$